# Checking Umbraco node length

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I have a panel that is created and filled via a vacancy page I have created. Im doing it as follows:

```
@{
    var root = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1);
    var newsNode = root.Descendants("News").First();
    var vacanciesNode = root.Descendants("Vacancies").First();
    string shortenedSummary = string.Empty;
}

<ul>
    @foreach (var vacancyItem in vacanciesNode.Descendants("Vacancy").Take(3).OrderBy("postDate desc"))
    {
        <p>here we are 2</p>
        @vacanciesNode.Count().ToString()
        <li>
            <h4><a href="@vacancyItem.Url">@vacancyItem.jobTitle</a></h4> <span>Posted on @vacancyItem.postDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</span>
            <p>
                @if (vacancyItem.jobSummary.Length <= 182)
                {
                    @vacancyItem.jobSummary
                }
                else
                {
                    shortenedSummary = vacancyItem.jobSummary.Substring(0, 182) + "...";
                    @shortenedSummary
                }
            </p>

            <a href="@vacancyItem.Url" class="btn btn-purple">Read More..</a>
        </li>
    }

</ul>
```

However, when there are no vacancy items, my list is empty. Should this be the case, I'm wanting it to read "sorry no vacancies just now" but I don't know how to check if my `vacanciesNode` has any items in it.

Could someone show me how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the .`Descendants()` method returns a `DynamicContentList` (a collection) you can simply do a `.Count()` on the collection and check whether it's more than or equal to 1.

If there's more than 0 items in the collection, it's not empty.

So, what you need to do is surround your `@foreach` with an `@if` statement which checks on this, and an `else` statement after that prints whatever html you want to show if there's no vacancies

```
@if( vacanciesNode.Descendants("Vacancy").Take(3).OrderBy("postDate desc").Count() > 0) {
   //Do foreach
}
else
{
   //Write message about missing vacancies
}
```